# Hiding frame: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, dom, nuxt.js

I'm trying to set the chatbot I use on the site that I wrote using Nuxt .js to appear on some pages and not on others. However, I am getting an error on the pages I want to hide.

I implemented the chatbot as script tags in app.html. On the pages that I do not want to appear, I write it as follows in mounted:

```
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("fc_frame")
  element.classList.add("d-none");
```

However, the page drops to 500 error and I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
```

error in the console. Do you have any suggested solution?

Answer (score 0):

One solutions it is when there's only one element with the fc_frame class, you can use querySelector instead of getElementsByClassName.
like that:
var element = document.querySelector(".fc_frame");

IquerySelector returns the first element with the fc_frame class (or null if there's no matching element). Then, we add the d-none class to the element's classList if the element exists.

Comment: I tried but I got TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

Comment: send me your code and i will fix this